# Build Any() with Expression Trees for LINQ Queries

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

I'm building a SQL "Any" clause dynamically using the System.Linq.Expressions.Expression class

I can do it like this

```
Expression<Func<User, Lead, bool>> predicate = (user, lead) => user.UserRoleSubProducts.Any(x => x.SubProductID == lead.SubProductID);
```

But I am not able to achieve this using Expression Tree.

I have tried below

```
var param1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(User), "user");
var property1 = Expression.Property(param1, "UserRoleSubProducts");
var exp1 = Expression.Lambda(property1, new[] { param1 });

var param2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Lead), "lead");
var property2 = Expression.Property(param2, "SubProductID");
var exp2 = Expression.Lambda(property2, new[] { param2 });

var param3 = Expression.Parameter(property1.Type.GetProperty("Item").PropertyType, "x");
var property3 = Expression.Property(param3, "SubProductID");
var exp3 = Expression.Lambda(property3, new[] { param3 });

var equality = Expression.Equal(property2, property3);

var any = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == "Any").Single(m => m.GetParameters().Length == 2).MakeGenericMethod(property1.Type);

var expression = Expression.Call(null, any, property1, equality);
```

But getting

> Expression of type
>   'Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceCollection`1[Api.Models.UserRoleSubProduct]' cannot be used for parameter of type System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceCollection`1[Api.Models.UserRoleSubProduct]]' of method 'Boolean Any[DataServiceCollection`1](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceCollection`1[Api.Models.UserRoleSubProduct]],
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceCollection`1[Api.Models.UserRoleSubProduct],System.Boolean]])'

I think I am close enough. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ignoring the redundant unused lambda expressions, the problem is in the last 2 lines.

First, you are using a wrong generic type (`MakeGenericMethod(property1.Type)`), while the correct type is basically the type of the parameter `x` here

```
.Any(x => x.SubProductID == lead.SubProductID)
```

=>

```
.Any<T>((T x) => ...)
```

which maps to `param3.Type` in your code.

Second, the second argument of the `Any` must be lambda expression (not simply `equality` as in the code).

Third, since `user.UserRoleSubProducts` most likely is a collection type, you should emit call to `Enumerable.Any` rather than `Queryable.Any`.

The `Expression.Call` method has [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351107(v=vs.110).aspx) which is very handy for "calling" static generic extension methods:

```
public static MethodCallExpression Call(
    Type type,
    string methodName,
    Type[] typeArguments,
    params Expression[] arguments
)
```

So the last two lines can be replaced with:

```
var anyCall = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Enumerable), nameof(Enumerable.Any), new Type[] { param3.Type },
    property1, Expression.Lambda(equality, param3)
);
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. Your help is highly appreciated